# "Redundant code detection" works differently on protected or higher scoped properties and fields

Tags: c#, resharper

In the following code example, R# will tell me that the assignment is redundant.
Which makes perfect sense to me.

```
private string _name = null;   // Redundant code warning
```

However, things are different, as soon as the field / property gets protected or higher

```
protected string Name = null; // No Redundant code warning
```

Is this a bug in R# or is there a reason behind?

Comment: Yeah looks odd, never noticed that yet ^^

Comment: Because it's not necessarily redundant? I'm guessing that, if you seal the class, you get the warning back. But haven't tried it.

Comment: Well when sealed, protected will be warned on, so lets ignore that fact, still i dont see why this wont be redundant. Can you explain your reasons here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because without looking for deriving classes, ReSharper can't tell if it's used or not, so it errs on the side of caution and assumes it is used, somewhere. If you enable Solution Wide Analysis, ReSharper will be able to see the whole solution, and will know if the field is used in a derived class or not. Then it will show the redundant code warning.

Comment: Of course, solution-wide analysis is only as good as the solution. You may want a "master solution" that includes all of the projects which reference each other. I think that's called a [_closure_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28mathematics%29) in mathematics.

Comment: Its not about the usage of the field or property. I dont think this is an answer to the question. Its about the initial assignment to the default value, and i cant see how a derived class would cause any difference on this.

Comment: @CSharpie no, this is the correct answer. Your question was specifically about ReSharper's highlighting of a redundant null assignment, and @citizenmatt's answer explained why ReSharper doesn't flag the `protected` field by default (you need to turn on Solution-Wide Analysis for it to flag it as well). So it's not a bug, but you need to enable this explicitly yourself. In any case, assigning a default value (`null`, in this case) to a field is always redundant, because the compiler does it for you.

Comment: Ok, i understand, though i dont see why you need to enable soloutionwide analysis before it does flag in that case aswell.
This part makes no sense to me, especially since solutionwide analysis is a huge performance killer. So we can agree that there is no real reason behind this behaviour, since there is no case (language wise impossible) where this is not redundant

Comment: The reason it doesn't flag is because it's based on what's happening in the constructor. ReSharper doesn't complain about setting the field to a default value (though strictly speaking that is redundant too). Instead it's complaining that setting a value in a field initialiser AND the constructor is redundant. And if the field is protected, it can't tell this is happening unless it looks in all derived classes' constructors, which requires solution wide analysis.

Comment: @citizenmatt that gave me the 'aha' i was looking for. Thanks